# multilevel menu activation activation

Tags: html, css

This doesn't work for me I have it like this:

```
A = first level link
[menu-link:parent:url:path]
B = second level link
[menu-link:parent:url:path]
C = third level link
[node:menu-link:parent:url:path]
```

Am I doing something wrong?

first level menu:

```
<ul class="topmenu">
    <li><a id="new">a</a></li>
    <li><a id="new1">b</a></li>
</ul>
```

second and thrid level menu:

```
<div id="con">
    <ul>
        <li>a1</li>
        <li>a2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="acc">
    <ul>
        <li>b1</li>
        <li><a href="b2.aspx">b2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

in first level menu using jquery:

```
$("#new").click(function () {

    $("#con").show();
    $("#acc").hide();

}

$("#new1").click(function () {

    $("#acc").show();
    $("#con").hide();

}
```

but can i click b2 menu highlight the new1 first level  menu and acc div is show but is not working.
can i click b2 menu higlight new1-firstlevel menu and con div second level menu is not right.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're exactly trying to achieve, can you explain a bit clearer? One thing, close your function, edit `}` to `});`

Answer (score 0):

You want b1+b2 showed when b is clicked, and a1+a2 when a is clicked?

If so, your function is okay (expect not closing the function).

```
$("#new").click(function () {
    $("#con").show();
    $("#acc").hide();
});

$("#new1").click(function () {
    $("#acc").show();
    $("#con").hide();
});
```

Check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/X7E62/).

I added this to the stylesheet, so both submenu's don't show on page load.

```
#con, #acc {
    display: none;
}
```